# Angular 9 SEO via Angular Universal issue

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-universal

I've got next error

```
NetworkError
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:341661:19)
    at Observable._subscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:20714:17)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:303054:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:303040:22)
    at scheduleTask (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:107437:32)
    at Observable._subscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:107499:13)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:303054:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:303040:22)
    at subscribeToResult (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:313135:23)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (PATH_TO_PROJECT\dist\frontend\server\main.js:308325:116)
```

I have no idea how to fix that....

Comment: Are you using absolute urls when making API requests?

Comment: Yep! Also app working correctly, but i have many errors in console (not in the browser), each request starts with http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/...

Comment: SSR is probably not working correctly. I guess network requests fail server side and the data is not prerendered, but you still still correct data in the front because of client side rendering. Make sure `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api` is accessible from your server, e.g. doing a curl call from the machine running the ssr server

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @SvetoslavAtanasov yes but i don't remember how